# CommunicationsException when connecting from GAE to MySQL Instance

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine

I'm trying to connect from inside GAE (Google App Engine) to my MySQL DB instance, also on GAE. It works fine from the outside.

After a week of searching, I cannot seem to find the problem.

Without the MySQL connection code, the servlet works fine without errors on GAE.

Here is the simple servlet:

```
public class DBServlet extends HttpServlet {
        @Override
        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://cloud-2280:mysql/account", "root", "");
                //Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://cloud-1180:mysql/account?user=root");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DBServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DBServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                try {
                        conn.close();
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(DBServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

When tying this on GAE, I get this in the GAE logs:

> com.conversedynamics.NewServlet doPost: null
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the
>   server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets
>   from the server. at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:46) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:668) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1078) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2417) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2450)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2235)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:818) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:46) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:46) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleNonRegisteringDriver$JdbcWrapper.getInstance(GoogleNonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleNonRegisteringDriver.connect(GoogleNonRegisteringDriver.java:252)
>   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571) at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233) at
>   com.conversedynamics.NewServlet.doPost(NewServlet.java:90) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404) at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
>   at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
>   at
>   com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
>   at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
>   at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
>   at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to
>   read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost. at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3039) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:592)

And here is the appengine-web.xml

```
<application>cloud-2280</application>
    <version>1</version>
    <!--    <ssl-enabled>false</ssl-enabled>
    <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
    -->
    <threadsafe>false</threadsafe>
    <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
</appengine-web-app>
```

**UPDATE: Screen shot in relation to koma's answer:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a second generation cloud sql  instance. These are not accessible from app engine yet. Use a first generation instance and you can add your app as an authorized app. I had the same problem.

Comment: Wow, this is very interesting Aerodyno. I am using a second generation MySQL instance. Would like to slap someone at Google for not warning about this. I'll try it out and I promise that I'll come back and mark the answer as correct if it works. Not sure how long it will take me to make a new MySQL first generation instance and create the tables and data. But do give me a few days. If I don't come back, everybody on SOF may mark me down. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are right @Aerodyno, didn't consider that possibility... only when running managed VMs you can access a 2nd generation through a proxy, see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sql-proxy#gae

Comment: Indeed it seems to work now! Thank you so much Aerodyno and koma too. Really appreciate the help. The GAE app and the MySQL instance also need to be in the same zone. Also, it was not possible to connect with the IPv6 address (maybe a rooter or network card on my side that isn't setup for IPv6). So I had to enable IPv4 @ $0.01/hour. Where the second generation instance is free, the first generation MySQL instance is $0.025 per hour minimum.

Comment: Correction: It seems it is actually $0.025/hour minimum, when the server is up.....and $0.01/hour (for the IPv4) when the server is down.

Answer (score 1):

`Communications link failure` usually indicates that you have no permission to connect.

Did you grant access to your CloudSQL instance for your GAE application ?

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/access-control#appengine

Comment: I am so happy, I could jump over the roof! It seems you are on the right track koma! In the console I see "Authorized Applications: None". Then I click on "Access Control" and "Authorization" and the "+", but there is no "Authorized App Engine Applications" section. I'll add the screen shot in a few minutes.

Comment: Is your GAE and CSQL in the same project ?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same project. Can't seem to add the screen shot now, there seems to be a small bug in the SOF edit script.

Comment: Managed to upload the screen shot. (One should click the other save button at the bottom).